# Gitlab CI and .NET Core - Can't get nuget cache with 2 stage build

Tags: caching, .net-core, gitlab

I have dockerfile like that:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env WORKDIR /app

    # Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers 
COPY *.csproj ./ 
COPY *.config ./ 
RUN dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config
    # Copy everything else and build 
COPY . ./ RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image 
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 
WORKDIR /app 
COPY --from=build-env /app/out . 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AuthService.dll"]
```

I cannot get for that on Gitlab build.

The whole Nuget cache sits in `build-env` under `~/.nuget/packages` but Gitlab somehow does not see that (I suppose it checks only last container.

Any idea how to solve it? It is making builds so long because of no NuGet cache...

Comment: Did you find out where it was putting it? I've tried `~/.nuget` and `.nuget` and both failed.

Answer (score 8):

`dotnet restore` by default stores the restored dependencies in the `.nuget/packages` directory in the user's home directory (`/home/user1` on Linux or `C:\Users\user1` on Windows). User's home directory is out of scope of GitLab cache. That's why you will not be able to cache dependencies stored in NuGet default directory.

But! `dotnet restore` comes with a `--packages` option with which you can specify where the restored packages are placed during restore operation. If you run

```
dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config --packages .nuget
```

A `.nuget` directory will be created in the current directory, thus making it available for caching and copying operations. You don't even need to worry about telling the program where the restored dependencies are stored, because that information is also saved during restore.

I created a [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214128/passing-restored-packages-as-artefacts-in-gitlab-continuous-integration) on Code Review for related issue I was having. There is a good chance you'll find there something of value.

Comment: A bit late to the party but is there an actual working example of this somewhere, we have been banging our heads for some time with this issue. It should be simpler. Read the posts linked above, but still not working.

Comment: If you are using Docker, then sadly I have nothing more to offer you. If it is just for .NET Core projects on GitLab, then checkout GitLab CI configuration file in my projects like [this one](https://gitlab.com/fluorite/strainer/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) covering building, testing, packing and deploying NuGet library or [this example GitLab CI template for .NET Core project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/dotNET-Core.yml) with extensive commentary.

Comment: Thank you @Prolog the link to your project seems like it would be a huge help. Not using docker so this should sort us out.

Comment: Are you able to share with me your build configuration, essentially what is being passed in for this `--configuration ${BUILD_CONFIGURATION}`

Comment: `${VARIABLE_NAME}` marks a variable, you can also just write `$VARIABLE_NAME` without the curly brackets. All public variables are listed at the top of the configuration file right after image specification. Since the linked configuration is for a library, it also comes with few private variables, stored in project CI/CD settings, for example a NuGet API key used for publishing the library. [This](https://gitlab.com/Prologh/business-activities/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) example may be easier to understand, as it's without pack & deploy stages, but do note different .NET Core version used.

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with variables and figured the build config was private, was just wondering if there was anything specific to getting the cache working. I have found out what the issue is, since we are using a self hosted version, the cache has not been configured and never gets uploaded. i got the artifacts working though, was missing the dependencies attribute which your example pointed out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I am building a multi stage .net docker image with GitLab-ci and caching the nuget packages by saving the intermediate images. This is working for a .net 5 asp project, but should work for the docker file above like this:

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    # target and cache build stage
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/build:latest || true
    - >
      docker build
      -f PathTo/Dockerfile
      -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/build:latest
      --cache-from ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/build:latest
      --target build-env
      .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/build:latest
    # target and cache final stage
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - >
      docker build 
      -f PathTo/Dockerfile 
      -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
      --cache-from ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
      --cache-from ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/build:latest
      .
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
  tags: 
    - docker
```

See here for more info: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34715

Answer (score 0):

My problem was while using the Gitlab CI within docker container. So the answer might be a little bit different than what you expect.

By trying many things I found out where was the issue. The Gitlab CI is putting the `.nuget` folder under the `~/` (home) directory of the user. However, when you start your CI, the folder you start with is not the `~/` folder and don't find the `.nuget`. In order to make it work in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I have done the following:

```
# Some stuff before
build-dotnet: 
  image: microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk-jessie
  stage: build
  cache:
    paths:
      - nuget

  script: 
    - (if [ -d ./nuget ]; then mv nuget ~/.nuget; else echo "No nuget cache available"; fi); # Fail on first attempt, but will work after.
    - # etc.
    - mv ~/.nuget nuget
# Some stuff after
```

I hope it helps